# How to customize Liberty Profile(8.5.5.5-cl50520150305-2202) Welcome Page?

Tags: websphere-liberty

I am required to change and customize the Liberty Profile Welcome page

```
<httpDispatcher enableWelcomePage="false"/>
```

I have used above tag to hide it but the page is displaying

> **Not Found**

like this

[image]

How can I change the Welcome page?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own app, create welcome page there and deploy it under `/` root context. There is no way to customize built in welcome page.